# Zend Controller redirect in init() method

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function init(){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['administrator'])){
            $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRouteAndExit(array('controller' => 'index', 'module' => 'cp', 'action' => 'login'), null,!0,!0);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried on Firefox, it shows me:

***Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.***

But when I put redirector outside of init() method, it works.

```
public function indexAction(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['administrator'])){
        $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRouteAndExit(array('controller' => 'index', 'module' => 'cp', 'action' => 'login'), null,!0,!0);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

**Edit:**

I don't want to repeat the "redirect code" because there are many other actions need to be checked permission in the same controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that on `index/login`, you also run the `init()` method, detect that the user is not an admin, and try to again redirect him to `index/login`, which will run the `init()` method again, detect that he still is not an admin... and so on. Thus the infinite redirect loop.

So in your `init()` you may first check if you are trying to call the `login` action, and only if not, check for admin permissions and redirect to `index/login`.

In your concrete case, you may want to change your `init()` method as follows:

```
public function init(){
    if ($this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'login' && !isset($_SESSION['administrator'])){
        $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRouteAndExit(array('controller' => 'index', 'module' => 'cp', 'action' => 'login'), null,!0,!0);
    }
}
```

This excludes the `login` action from checking admin permissions and redirecting, breaking the infinite redirect loop.

Comment: I think it is not good solution on my project but anyway, thanks!
I'm sorry, I speak English not well.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, `init()` function will always runs first in any controller,

So When you do a redirect is `init()` it essential redirects to itself , which will create infinite loop in your case, so it will keep redirecting to itself, as "BluePsyduck" Suggested.

So do the alternate what you have already done and redirect it in `index Action` of your controller..

Comment: @Dragon Warrior `init()` is not a function. It method of class.

Comment: oh really , i was indicating at the fact that we do write it as `public function init()` don't we ?